# WSO2 5.3.0 Email template is not updating

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2IS 5.3.0 version.
I updated all the configs but mistakenly i gave wrong password reset url in [IS_HOME]/repository/conf/email/email-admin-config.xml file. I started my server with RDBMS as datasource. Everything worked well.

Then I noticed my password reset url is wrong. Again I went to [IS_HOME]/repository/conf/email/email-admin-config.xml file and updated the url and restarted WSO2. But it is not working for all the users. Some users still getting old template with wrong url. I restarted my WSO2 multiple times and updated the xml file but no luck. I even tried to change the template through carbon admin UI but still it is sending wrong template.

The weird thing is it is sending right one immediately after i restart WSO2 but after sometimes it start using old template. How can I solve this issue without reconfigure everything from beginning?

Answer (score 5):

Let's me explain how the email-admin-config.xml works. This file works as the bootstrap data required to populate email templates in WSO2 Identity Server. So whenever you create a tenant initial data related to email templates will be read from here.

So we basically read the file during the **first startup** (ie. creation of carbon.super tenant) and **any new tenant creation** of the server and write the content to the database. Thereafter any change you want to do needs to be done with the UI provided in the Managment Console.

Restarting the server won't make the changes apply to existing tenants that were created before changes were made to email-admin-config.xml. But if you create a new tenant the updated content will be read from the email-admin-config.xml.

Hope this clarifies your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @farasath's answer. You can also use a SOAP service to change the template programmatically. For that, you can use `AccountCredentialMgtConfigService`. The service contract can be accessed from.

`https://<host>:<port>/services/AccountCredentialMgtConfigService?wsdl`

However to access the WSDL, you have to set `HideAdminServices` property to `false` first at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` and restart the server.

Also, in the management console, the email template management UI can be found under `Manage` section on the left side panel.

[image]